# Where to put source java files in grails 4.0.8 while upgrading from grails 2.0.8?

Tags: intellij-idea, grails

I am having project view based upon Grails 4.0.8. I am upgrading it from Grails 2.2.4 therefore src/main/java package classes need to re adjusted under Grails 4.0.8. I am putting it under src folder but i am getting several importing class error in intellij editor. I am being unable to resolve import package error in spite of of class present under src/java/com/../../.

[Link for my project view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zooc.png)

In java folder under project view, i am putting .java files then i am getting error.

Answer (score 1):

I think classes should be under `src/main/groovy`. in order to take advantage of join compiler's bi-directional dependency support. Please checkout https://grails.github.io/grails-upgrade/latest/guide/index.html#upgrading2x

Also, I think you could just write Groovy classes instead of Java to avoid code ceremonies.

@Jeff Scott Brown Thank you for correcting me.